# Sharing Dial up internet with android

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet, android

I am running Windows 7 with symantec endpoint protection antivirus. I have a dial up connection to connect to internet.

I want to create a hotspot to share this internet connection with andriod phone (Moto G-Lolipop).

I hae tried connectify, mhotspot, mypublicwifi, virtualrouter etc.

I create a hotspot on all of these and connect my mobile to the hotspot. But I could NOT browse internet through this hotspot.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: "But I could browse internet through this hotspot." should read "could **not** browse"?